# Weekly statistics on broken build/claims in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to send a weekly mail to all developers and testers on how many broken builds we have had and also a scoring on those who have made most claims. Any easy way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script that gets the info from the [Jenkins REST API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API), although I'm not sure if the claim information will be available; that comes from a plugin, and not all plugins provide extensions to the API.

Post back here if you need any guidance.